# MS Excel multiple conditions to fulfil before providing status

Tags: excel, function, conditional-statements

I need to set several functions in a single formula but no matter what I do, Excel will prompt errors.

Could someone please help me with the following:

```
Admin date Deadline Amount A Amount B Status
```

The Admin date will source for data from another table via VLookup.
 The Deadline is auto computed using excel formula to calculate using Admin date
 Amount A and Amount B are to be manually entered

I am stuck with the formula for the Status...

Priority 1: To check if there is feedback(from VLookup) of information for Admin date, if none, to set Status as 'N/A'

Priority 2: If there is feedback for Admin date, to check whether the Deadline has past today's date. If yes, to set Status as 'Overdue'

Priority 3: If Deadline has not past today's date, to check whether there is any value in both Amount A or Amount B. If both are blank, to set Status as 'Pending' BUT if there is any amount in either Amount A or Amount B, to set the Status as 'Complete'.

Sample Table:

[image: Sample Table]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Assuming the image/table above, ( Column A = Results from your VLookup, B- the date, C - Amount A , D- Amount B....)
The following should works.

```
=IF(A2="","N/A",IF(B2="","N/A",IF(B2<TODAY(),"Overdue",IF(OR(C2<>"",D2<>""),"Complete","Pending"))))
```

Comment: I don't think so,
as the (if-overdue) is the parent of (if-amount,a-b)..
It can't 'overrule' it..unless (if-overdue) is false..